# Send 2 Images from Socket server

Tags: java, python, sockets

I would like to send 2 Images from Socket server (Java) to client socket (python).

--> My Problem I received ONLY ONE Image (dataImage1) in client.

What Have I Done Wrong?

I send (java) the images  successively:

```
 ...
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read (file);
 imgstr = encodeToString(image, "png");
 outToClient.writeBytes(imgstr);
 ...
 BufferedImage chart = ImageIO.read (fileChart);
 imgstrChart = encodeToString(chart, "png");
 outToClient.writeBytes(imgstrChart);
 ...
```

I receive (python) the images successively:

```
  ...
  client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  server_addr = (tcpclient.host , tcpclient.port)
  client_socket.connect( server_addr )
  dataImage1 = client_socket.recv( 1024 )
  fp = open ( pathImage1, "wb" )
  while dataImage1:
      #{
      if not dataImage1: break
      recvDataImage += dataImage1
      dataImage1 = client_socket.recv( 1024 )
      #}
  fp.write(b64decode( recvDataImage1 ))
  fp.flush()
  fp.close()

  dataImage2 = client_socket.recv( 1024 )
  fp = open ( pathImage2, "wb" )
  while dataImage2:
      #{
      if not dataImage2: break
      recvDataImage2 += dataImage2
      dataImage2 = client_socket.recv( 1024 )
      #}
  fp.write(b64decode( recvDataImage2 ))
  fp.flush()
  fp.close()
  ....
```

Comment: Did you `flush()` the OutputStream on the java side ?

Comment: you mean:
 
         outToClient.writeBytes(imgstrChart); 
  outToClient.flush();

Comment: Yes exactly that .

Comment: I just get the first Image , so the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

How does the receiver know where image1 ends? In your code, the client keeps calling `client_socket.recv` until a null string is returned. This doesn't happen until the socket is closed. So what is happening is that you are transmitting both images and the client is writing the content of both to the first file.

The second loop will never receive any data because, once closed, you will never receive more data from the socket.

You need to either (a) open a new socket to transmit the second file, or (b) send the length of each file as part of your protocol so that the client knows how much to write to `pathImage1` before moving on to `pathImage2`.

Comment: Thank you Gil, which solution is better now? I say the 2nd (b). right?
when I correctly understand, I have to tie the Images together with the length each Image before to send it to client?.

Comment: They both have their advantages. Easiest to implement IMO, is (a): have the client connect, send to the server the name of the file it wants to receive next, then it can just receive the entire thing in one fell swoop and write it to a file. If only the server knows which files are to be transferred, you would need to use (b): include the filename and size info inline which means establishing a protocol. That can either be a "text-based" protocol like HTTP (provide name and size in text followed by newline, then the file content), or a binary protocol (where you encode/decode binary fields).